# How to search for and report IP in all files using Linux shell script

Tags: linux, string, shell, file, search

I am very new at this:

This Linux script currently works as designed.

I would like to alter or rewrite it to continue to search all 3 files for the IP and report accordingly i.e., "IP is in group 1 and 3" or
"IP is in group 1
IP is in group 3"

Looking for some help understanding how to structure it to do so. Thanks.

```
clear
echo -n "Enter the IP address"
read ip
echo ""
echo "Searching for $ip"
sleep 1
echo ""
if grep -wq $ip /system/config/channels/group1.yml; then
    echo "IP is in group1"
    echo ""
elif grep -wq $ip /system/config/channels/group2.yml; then
    echo "IP is in group2"
    echo ""
elif grep -wq $ip /system/config/channels/group3.yml; then
    echo "IP is in group3"
    echo ""
else
    echo "IP not found. Exiting..."
    echo ""
fi
```

Comment: Get rid of your `elifs` and make 3 if statements, set a counter in each when the IP is found, then test the counter for 0 and echon not found?

Comment: Need to know what file(s) contain(s) the IP

Answer (score 1):

As @tink said just remove `elif`
Add a var for the not found message

```bash
clear
echo -n "Enter the IP address"
read ip
echo ""
echo "Searching for $ip"
sleep 1
echo ""
not_found=true
if grep -wq $ip /system/config/channels/group1.yml; then
    echo "IP is in group1"
    echo ""
    not_found=false
fi
if grep -wq $ip /system/config/channels/group2.yml; then
    echo "IP is in group2"
    echo ""
    not_found=false
fi
if grep -wq $ip /system/config/channels/group3.yml; then
    echo "IP is in group3"
    echo ""
    not_found=false
fi
if $not_found; then
    echo "IP not found. Exiting..."
    echo ""
fi
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You guys have been a tremendous help.

Comment: Maybe make the variable names lowercase - uppercase is reserved for system use.

Comment: @tink lowercase done